# Insert the 'html' tag before the 'head' tag (not in or between them) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to insert a comment before the 'html' tag and before the doctype tag (if present), like...

```
<!-- Hello, World! -->
```

From a previous quest, the following code did the job where an attribute was to be inserted "inside" a tag. However, this quest is different...

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].setAttribute("id", "something");
```

How can I insert "before" the nominated tag?

Comment: Can't you do it on the server side? Do you have to to it on client?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be client side, after a browser condition is tested to signify its requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't any guarantees about browser support, but this works in Firefox and Chrome:

```
var comment = document.createComment("HelloWorld");

document.insertBefore(comment, document.firstChild);
```

And FYI, you don't insert before "tags" after the HTML is parsed. You insert into the DOM before a DOM node.

Comment: I was going to go with `document.insertBefore(comment, document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]`, but it's less reliable and apparently can end up inserting after the html node. +1 to you!